# Trying to use Xdebug on docker with VS Code in MacOS leads to Error address already in use

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I've been trying to use Xdebug in Docker with VSCode in MacOS.
But, if I expose the docker port 9003 (or any other), it fails when VS Code attempts to listen on that port because the port is being used already.

Xdebug configuration inside docker

```ini
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
```

In docker-compose's service:

```yaml
ports:
  # Other ports exposed, not relevant to this
  - "9003:9003"
```

launch.json:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen to docker",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html/app": "${workspaceFolder}/"
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

If I run docker and then try to debug I get the following in VS code:

```
Listening to Xdebug on 0.0.0.0:9003 failed: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:9003
Listening to Xdebug on :::9003 failed: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::9003
```

If I remove exposing the port, VS Code starts to listen, but then the docker instance can't reach the IDE.

I've tried using other ports, I've tried using `network_mode=host`, but then docker fails to start.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See [Xdebug 3: Xdebug with Docker and PhpStorm in 5 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4opFac50Vwo), especially the part how to configure  xdebug in the docker container and note the required docker version. Albeit you only have VSCode at hand, not PhpStorm, the part important to your configuration should become obvious (you can skip the part about Phpstorm), the important part is the Xdebug and Docker configuration. The IDE is listening, not a service in the Docker container. Port 9003 is in use already (don't re-use it on the Docker container).

Comment: As hakre said -- having `- "9003:9003"` is wrong. Xdebug connection is an outgoing connection (from the container to the host) while exposing the port will make Docker listening on it and forward connections from the host into the container. As a result VSCode is unable to listen on that port. What if you add `"hostname": "0.0.0.0."` in your launch.json -- will it do any better? Check what Xdebug log has to say (enable it in php.ini)

Comment: So, the question is how do I make the docker service see my host port in MacOs?

Answer (score 0):

As answered before by LazyOne, do not expose port 9003 in your `docker-compose` because it is PHP/Xdebug that connects to the IDE, not the other way around.

VsCode PHP-Debug will by default listen on 0.0.0.0 the only thing to check is if your Dockerized PHP process can resolve `host.docker.internal` and connect to it.

I suggest you add `xdebug_info();` to a test.php file and try to debug it.